# RSS Feed Xcode 4.2

Tags: html, xcode, parsing, rss, xcode4.2

A fundamental part of my xcode 4.2 project is using HTML Parse. As no one has a good tutorial for storyboard using HTML Parsing, this is becoming less of an option—I have had to move on to an RSS feed reader. But no one has a tutorial using this with storyboards, only tutorials with xibs.

Does anyone have suggestions and/or advice?